# Illustrator gradient fill makes jaggies between colors if angle is changed

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

I have a 4 color gradient fill angled at 40 degrees (maybe its not the best way to achieve what I want) and the lines where colors meet are having [jaggies.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NV8C.png)

I have attached a screenshot of the gradient settings and the actual result. I would like to know if there is a way to make those edges smooth.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried making tiny transition areas between the colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is typically due to Illustrator anti-aliasing for screen. Upon printing or saving for web that should get smoothed out.

This comes from the fact that Illustrator is creating vector data and then trying to render a preview in pixels for the screen. Sometimes artwork can look less-than-smooth. However, in most cases it prints/exports just fine.

Nothing wrong with the gradient, but I'm curious why you wouldn't simply use 4 shapes?

Comment: True, after generating the image, it smooths out.

Comment: Just a pointless note :) When Illustrator is optimized for and used on a retina display this issue will be practically non-existent. And it was MUCH worse 10 years ago.